# Bing Translator Python using Sublime Text

Tags: python

may I know if there is a solution to change my code in order to translate the website from Malay to English language but using Bing Translator instead.

```py
import pandas
import urllib.request as ur
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
url = "http://https://www.bharian.com.my/"
page = ur.urlopen(url)
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=["Title", "Date", "Url", "Content"])
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
headlines = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ms-vb itx"})
intro = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "ms-rtestate-field"})
dates = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "ms-vb2"})
count = len(headlines)

for i in range(0, len(headlines)):
    s = str(headlines[i].a.string)
    url1 = headlines[i].a.get("href")
    page1 = ur.urlopen(url1)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page1, "html.parser")
    cont = soup1.find_all("div", {"style": "text-align:justify;"})
    content = intro[2 * i].p.text

    for data in cont:
        content += data.text

content = translator.translate(content, src="ms", dest="en").text
s = translator.translate(s, src="ms").text
df = df.append(
    {
        "Title": s,
        "Date": dates[i].string,
        "Url": url1,
        "Content": content,
    },
    ignore_index=True,
)

df.to_csv("News.csv")
# f.write(str(len(result))+'\n')
# for res in result:
#   f.write(str(res.pre.string))
# f.close()
# while(driver.current_url == url):
#   continue
```

Comment: What your code is doing now?

Comment: @Alderven Print out CSV file. Working fine. But i just need to translate using Bing translator

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, but you might not like it very much. Right now it looks like you're using the `googletrans` library from PyPi - https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/. A similar-looking package exists for Bing translate called `bing_translator`, however it looks as though this package is out-of-date. Microsoft themselves, however, have published code samples on [GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-Python):

```py
import os, requests, uuid, json

key_var_name = 'TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY'
if not key_var_name in os.environ:
    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(key_var_name))
subscription_key = os.environ[key_var_name]

endpoint_var_name = 'TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPOINT'
if not endpoint_var_name in os.environ:
    raise Exception('Please set/export the environment variable: {}'.format(endpoint_var_name))
endpoint = os.environ[endpoint_var_name]

# If you encounter any issues with the base_url or path, make sure
# that you are using the latest endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-translate
path = '/translate?api-version=3.0'
params = '&to=de&to=it'
constructed_url = endpoint + path + params

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}

# You can pass more than one object in body.
body = [{
    'text' : 'Hello World!'
}]
request = requests.post(constructed_url, headers=headers, json=body)
response = request.json()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

As you've probably noticed, this is a fair bit clunkier than your nice googletrans package. You might want to make your own abstraction layer to make this easier (and maybe publish it on PyPi!).

`TRANSLATOR_TEXT_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY` and `TRANSLATOR_TEXT_ENDPONT` should be filled in with your Translation service endpoint and subsciption keys. Whilst Google seem happy enough for you to freely use their API, Microsoft would like you to create an account. Whilst it looks like you can get hold of a free key, depending on what you're using it for Microsoft might expect payment. The links on the github page should take you to the relevant articles for that.

Comment: is there any possible to edit my code above in order to use this bing translator? couldn't get it.

Comment: @Faker, It is definitely possible to rewrite your code to use Bing, but I'm not going to do it; Stack Overflow is not a code writing service and the changes to make aren't trivial, not least because Google Translate has an easy-to-use pip package whilst Bing translate does not. You should probably start by trying to use the Microsoft documentation to make the code sample I posted work for you, and then build a simple class around that code sample which you can import into your code.